# How do I create a session with a bool method?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, boolean

Im having a problem. My session works fine, when I use a public DataTable method. But Im expanding my login security. So Im now using a public Bool metod.

I dont know how to use Session in the following code? This is the button:
(The UserLogin is a Bool, and GetUser i a DataTable (comment)

```
protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dtUser = new DataTable();

    if (txtBrugernavn.Text != "" && txtAdgangskode.Text != "")
    {
        if (objLogin.UserLogin(txtBrugernavn.Text, txtAdgangskode.Text))
        {
             // Session here!   
             Response.Redirect("Admin/Default.aspx");

        }
        else
        {
            litResult.Text = "<div class='error'>Du har skrevet forkert brugernavn eller adgangskode</div>";
        }

    }

    //DataTable dtUser = new DataTable();
    //dtUser = objLogin.GetUser(txtBrugernavn.Text, txtAdgangskode.Text);

    //if (dtUser.Rows.Count > 0)
    //{
    //    Session["Username"] = dtUser.Rows[0]["fldUsername"];

    //    Response.Redirect("Admin/Default.aspx");
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    litResult.Text = "<div class='error'>Du har skrevet forkert brugernavn eller adgangskode</div>";
    //}

}
```

Here is the bool method:

public bool UserLogin(string Username, string Password)
    {

```
    bool UserExist = false;
    objCMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT fldSalt FROM tblUsers WHERE fldUserName = @Username");
    objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
    if (objData.GetData(objCMD).Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        kryptering objKryptering = new kryptering();
        string salt = objData.GetData(objCMD).Rows[0]["fldSalt"].ToString();

        objCMD = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblUsers WHERE fldUserName = @Username AND fldPassword = @Password");
        objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", Username);
        objCMD.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", objKryptering.HashPassword(Password, salt));
        if (objData.GetData(objCMD).Rows.Count > 0)
        {
            UserExist = true;
        }
    }

    return UserExist;
}
```

Comment: have you considered out parameter?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Still getting the Datatable out of your UserLogin-Method? As Ratna suggested use an out-Parameter or a Result-Object instead of a bool.

Comment: I put the bool method in the question.. But im not sure how to do that?